# Sump Pump not able to pump to ground/exhaust level

Tags: plumbing, sump-pump

I have a sump pump in my basement that is not able to pump water up to the house exterior exhaust, which is about 10 feet above it.

If allow the water to exit the exhaust a few feet above the sump well it can drain out just fine. However, it will not fill the exhaust pipe high enough to get the water to ground level. I have it off for now or it will just run continuously.

It starts/stops with the floater level just fine. The one-way valve seems to open OK. Looking in the sump well I can see the water swirling around while the pump is running. There are no blockages in the exhaust

Is the motor shot? Do I need a new pump? It is probably the original sump pump from the house construction (2003)

Thanks!

Comment: it sounds like the pump needs a new propeller.  replacing the propeller should be fairly easy,  finding the correct part may be tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **motor** is probably fine, the pump parts themselves (that interact with the water, and any sand/grit/etc. in the water) may have worn too much, if it was ever up to the job in the first place. Being worn, they don't produce as much pressure as when unworn, and your discharge is too high for the pressure they can now manage.

Replacement parts *might* be available, but are often difficult to find .vs. a whole new pump (the wonders of the "modern economy.")

Pay attention to "maximum discharge head" if shopping for a new one, or looking at the specs for your old one before throwing parts at it, if you can ID it and find parts to throw. *Some* sump pumps might not be up to 10 feet of head even when new.

Comment: If what you are saying the pump no longer has the capacity do do the job. They do wear out, and it is not always the motor. Your best and most reliable solution is to replace it. If you want you can rebuild the old one and keep it as a spare but be sure to test it first.

Comment: I pulled it out of the sump well and I think the chassis near the intake is cracked. Not sure of the exact failure mode but yeah I'll be replacing it.